# Call php function with jquery using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a php function that is defined on a php file.

On the php file I have this that will call the function

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
    submit();    //Do something with your GET
}
```

But I'm getting an error when calling the php function within the jquery. I imagine it could be a path problem. The jquery file is in js/file.js and the php function is on data/php/function.php so I try it calling it like this.

```
       $.ajax({
          url: "../data/php/functions.php&paperid="+$('#table-paperid').text(),
          type: "GET",
          success:function(result)//we got the response
          {
           alert('Successfully called');
          },
          error:function(exception){alert('Exception:'+exception);}
       });
```

But no matter what I write on the url I always get the exception error. Any ideas?

Comment: Well firstly paths are relative to the page they're loaded on...

Comment: What error specifically are you getting?

Comment: Shouldn't that `&` in your URL be an `?`?

Comment: @wogsland simply Exception:[object Object]

Comment: Ok so @NiettheDarkAbsol was right all along. I was given the path relative to the js file and not the original loaded page. Now I changed that and it works fine. I will up vote both answers though since they both helped me but non were the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's better practice to use a POST ajax call in this case. You should also put the  "type" property before the "url" field, although, I doubt this is the source of the error. Try an ajax call that looks something like this.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/some/path',
      data: { paperid : $('#table-paperid').text()},
      success: function(data) {

        var response = JSON.parse(data);

      }
    })
```

and your php should be modified to.

```
if(isset($_POST['paperid']))
{
    submit();    //Do something with your GET
}
```

I've done this many times with no issue so hopefully this will solve your problem.

Best of luck!

Comment: Why does in this case is good practice to make a POST Request?

Comment: Because of the parameters. It makes more sense to use POST as it is cleaner.

Comment: I tried this and I'm still getting the exception error. The alert message is simply Exception:[object Object] so I can't really see what's happening. Could it have to do with the path?

Comment: So for the url I have ../data/php/functions.php

Comment: @Atirag change `alert(JSON.stringify(exception, null, 4));` instead `alert('Exception:'+exception);` to see the error

Comment: @JoseRojas That was really helpful and, as I suspected, the path is incorrect. I get this "The requested URL /data/php/functions.php was not found on this server". So is it ignoring the "../"??

Answer (score 1):

You can set the query string this way as well:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "../data/php/functions.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {paperid: $('#table-paperid').text() }
      success:function(result)//we got the response
      {
       alert('Successfully called');
      },
      error:function(exception){alert('Exception:'+exception);}
   });
```